# Arcgis selecting polygons from irregular grid to remove isolated cells

Tags: python, polygon, spatial, arcgis, region

I have an irregular grid of triangles in one polygon shapefile. These cells are themed to show only triangles above my threshold level for 'interest'. Adjacent triangles, that are visible, are considered real. Spatially isolated triangles need to be removed as they could be spurious.

I can filter using definition query to remove the triangles below threshold but I cannot figure out how to remove the isolate triangles.

I'm aware that I probably need to use polygon neighbors

[screenshot from Arcgis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVBfT.png)

please send help!

Comment: Could you please share coordinates of 3 adjacent triangles and 3 spatially isolated triangles?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing similar kind of issue,so I did workaround and set appropriate threshold

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

coords1 = [(54.950899, 60.169158), (54.953492, 60.169158), (54.950958, 60.169990)]
poly1 = Polygon(coords1)

coords2 = [(24.950899, 60.169158), (24.953492, 60.169158), (24.950958, 60.169990)]
poly2 = Polygon(coords2)


poly1.distance(poly2)

# 29.997407

poly1.distance(poly1)

#0.0
```

You can set the threshold value to identify spatially isolated triangles

P.S. This workaround worked for me. This is solution is for your reference. Here Random polygons are taken.

Reference:
https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Near tool using the same features as the Input Features and Near Features. After if runs, check the attribute table for the new field NEAR_DIST, storing distances to the nearest features.

All records with a NEAR_DIST = 0 touch a polygon. Where the NEAR_DIST > 0 will be the spatially isolated polygons that you are after.